# Avoid using document.getElementById with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am making an application using Backbone.js, but I'm new to the Backbone.js. I need to change style property of HTML element. Is there way of using something from Backbone.js to change style of HTML element?

Inside index.html I put paragraph which is hidden:

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
<p id="error_msg_name1" style="display: none;">
    Please, enter the name of the configuration.
</p>
```

And when someone tries to save empty "name" inside the model, this paragraph should be shown, which I handled this way:

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
if (nameValue == '') {
    document.getElementById("error_msg_name1").style.display = 'inline';
}
```

My mentor told me that I shouldn't use `document.getElementById`, that I should use something from Backbone.js. I googled this for days, but I haven't found anything helpful.

This is my model:

```
var Configuration = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: function() {
      return {
          name: '',
          description: '',
          version: ''
      };
  }

});
```

And here is the View:

```
var ConfigurationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #ok': 'createConf',
        'click #cancel': 'cancelConf',
        'click #preview': 'showJSON',
        'click #readFile': 'readFile'
    },

    readFile: function() {
        var files = document.getElementById('fileInput').files;

        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                var fileContent = evt.target.result;
                document.getElementById('previewFile').textContent = fileContent;
                importedConfiguration = new Configuration(JSON.parse(fileContent));

                $('<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">\
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="update">Update</button>').appendTo('#for_button');
            }
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    },

    remove: function() {
        $(this.el).empty().detach();
        return this;
    },

    cancelConf: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    createConf: function() {

        document.getElementById("error_msg_name1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("error_msg_name2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("error_msg_description").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("error_msg_version").style.display = 'none';

        var nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

        var nameValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("description").value;
        var versionValue = document.getElementById("version").value;

        if (descriptionValue != ''  && versionValue != '' && nameRegex.test(nameValue)) {
            configuration.set({name: nameValue, description: descriptionValue, version: versionValue});

            document.getElementById("for_preview_JSON").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(configuration);
            document.getElementById("for_preview_JSON").disabled = true;

            var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(configuration));
            $('<a href="data:' + data + '" download="data.json">download JSON</a>').appendTo('#for_download_link_JSON');

            document.getElementById("ok").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("preview").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("description").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("version").disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            if (nameValue == '') {
                document.getElementById("error_msg_name1").style.display = 'inline';
            }else if(!nameRegex.test(nameValue)) {
                document.getElementById("error_msg_name2").style.display = 'inline';
            }

            if (descriptionValue == '') {
                document.getElementById("error_msg_description").style.display = 'inline';
            }
            if (versionValue == '') {
                document.getElementById("error_msg_version").style.display = 'inline';
            }
        }
    },

    showJSON: function() {
        var preview_conf = new Configuration({
            name: document.getElementById("name").value, 
            description: document.getElementById("description").value, 
            version: document.getElementById("version").value
        });
        document.getElementById("for_preview_JSON").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(preview_conf);
        document.getElementById("for_preview_JSON").disabled = true;
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this.template = options.template;
    },

    render: function(){
        var content = $(this.template).html();
        $(this.el).html(content);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any Backbone.View which wraps that index.html template?

Comment: Yes, I do. And this javascript part which I posted is from one function inside that View.

Comment: Could you post all view definition?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted code to your view, and how you implement your view (initialize it), so people can see what you're doing and if you're using the .el in the right way

Comment: I posted model and view.

Comment: In render function you using `this.template` reference, which is not defined, I guess it's index.html?

Comment: Yes, it's index.hmtl where I put template and all scripts which are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before any source code change I guess you need to understand how `Bakcbone.View` works and how you need to access/query the DOM in Backbone way.

Every time you are initializing `Backbone.View` like in your example and mentioning template, you can access your template with `this.$el`, which is jQuery element and references your template.

For your case you are doing a lot of unnecessary querying to the DOM. Instead of that just use `this.$el` to find/modify you template's HTML.

Example:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#your-template-id').html()),
    events: {
        "click .something": "doOtherThing"
    }, 
    doOtherThing: function (e) {
        // this.$el.find() same as this.$() within view.
        $myEl = this.$('.innerElement'); // cache element when you need to do a lot of manipulations   
        $myEl.addClass('changed'); // 
        $myEl.toggleClass('opened') // and so on...
    }
    render: function () {
        var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON);
        this.$el.append(template);
    } 
});

var myView = new MyView();
myView.render();
```

---

A few rules for you to remember:

**1. Don't query global**

If you need to add/remove/modify HTML element within view always use `this.$el` to access view.

**2. Cache commonly used elements**

```
 $myEl = this.$el.find('.innerElement'); 
 $myEl.addClass('changed');  
 $myEl.toggleClass('opened');
....
```

**3. Within `Bakcbone.View` `this.$el.find()` is same as `this.$()`**

Answer (score 1):

I would add something like this to your files

```
// before code
events: {
  // other events
  'click #save': 'saveEntry'
}
, saveEntry: function() {
  if( this.checkEmptyName() ) {
    // do other saving stuff
  }
}
, checkEmptyName: function() {
  var name = this.$el.find( '#name' ).val();
  if( name.length === 0 ) {
    this.$el.find( '#error_msg_name1' ).show();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
// everything else
```